# selectOneButton change listener always returning null

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2 along with primefaces, i have a selectOneButton which have 2 values, EN/FR, i want to be notified each time the language is changed, and then change the locale of the page, i have set valueChangeListener and an ajax event, 
but everytime the change listener is fired, the new value is always null!
here is the xhtml code:

```
<h:form id="f">
<p:selectOneButton id="lang" value="#{currentUser.language}" valueChangeListener="#{currentUser.languageChanged}" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Françcais" itemValue="fr" />
    <f:ajax event="change"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
</h:form>
```

the languageChanged method for testing:

```
public void languageChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        System.out.println("new val: " + event.getNewValue());
        System.out.println("old val: " + event.getOldValue());
    }
```

i even tried to attach to the ajax a listener:

```
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{currentUser.languageChanged}"/>
```

and the method:

```
public void languageChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        SelectOneButton button = (SelectOneButton)event.getComponent(); 
        System.out.println(button.getValue())   ;
    }
```

Is this the wrong way to retrieve the new selected value from a p:selectOneButton   with ajax?

UPDATE:
So i know what is causing this problem
actually my `selectOneButton` is inside a `menuItem` which is inside a `splitButton`, when i take the selectOneButton out side the splitButton it works fine!
why is the fact that the `selectOneButton` is inside the `menuItem` preventing it from send it to the server?
here the code:

```
<h:panelGroup style="float: right;" > 
    <h:form id="f">
        <p:splitButton value="#{currentUser.fullName}" icon="ui-icon-person" styleClass="toTheRight" style="min-width: 200px;" >
            <p:menuitem value="Matricule: #{currentUser.matricule}"  />
            <p:menuitem value="#{msgs.role}: #{currentUser.role}" />
            <p:separator />
            <p:menuitem>
                <p:selectOneButton id="lang" value="#{currentUser.language}" valueChangeListener="#{currentUser.languageChanged}" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Françcais" itemValue="fr" />
                    <f:ajax event="change"/>
                </p:selectOneButton>
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:separator />
            <p:menuitem value="#{msgs.settings}" icon="ui-icon-wrench"  />
            <p:menuitem value="#{msgs.logout}"  icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w" url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        </p:splitButton>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: It might also depend on the jsf Phase in which the valueChangeListener is called. `getLocalValue()` might work. Try it, I never used these.

Comment: but the locale is never set in the first place?

Comment: Locale? And if you try to retrieve it from the `submittedValue()`?

Comment: i figured out the problem, but not the solution .. updated

Comment: Inside the "menuItem"... Be sure the menuItem is inside a form...

Answer (score 2):

I have a similiar snap-code and that should work, here is what i have:

```
<p:outputLabel for="scriptMigrate" value="Migrate" style="font-weight:bold" />
<p:selectOneButton id="scriptMigrate" value="#{scriptConfiguration.scriptMigrate}" required="true">                          
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="0" />
    <p:ajax update="fsstobe" event="change" listener="#{scriptConfiguration.updateForm()}" />
</p:selectOneButton>
```

The `update` componetent is just for me to know what to render or not in the rest of the page, but here is the method:

```
public void updateForm() {
    System.out.println("entered with value: " + scriptMigrate);
    if (scriptMigrate.equals("1")) {
        renderScriptAsIs = true;
    }
    if (scriptMigrate.equals("0") || scriptMigrate.equals("")) {
        renderScriptAsIs = false;
    }
}
```

So i assume when you change the value you just want to call the method `languageChanged()`, so maybe my example helps, i have no arguments, try without them first to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
<p:ajax listener="#{currentUser.languageChanged}"/>
```

and remove the valueChangeListener from the selectOneButton.

In languageChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) just read the new value from the language-property.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{languageBean.languageName}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{languageBean.changeLanguage()}" partialSubmit="true"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="DE" itemValue="#{CONST.LANGUAGE_DE}"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="EN" itemValue="#{CONST.LANGUAGE_EN}" />
</p:selectOneButton>
```

and in the method from bean:

```
public void changeLanguage() {
System.out.println(languageName);
}
```